# Count values for each line in text file python

Tags: python, file

I think I am close to what I am trying to get, but I am still a begginer so don't really know if it is the best way. Let's say we have a file with hundred of lines where at the end of each one there is a value I want to count. It seems complex to me to program all in a single line of code so I prefer going step by step. Let's say we have a file with lines like the followings:

```
Type of line 1: 10
Type of line 1: 5
Type of line 1: 15
Type of line 2: 50
Type of line 2: 25
Type of line 2: 5
Type of line 3: 1
Type of line 3: 14
Type of line 3: 2
```

Since there is various type of lines what I am trying to get is the sum of those values which appear in the same type of line. For instance, the output should be this:

```
Type of line 1: 30
Type of line 2: 80
Type of line 3: 17
```

Type of line it is just a string.

So in order to achieve this first I read the file line by line and split each line using ':' character. Then I save those splitted lines in a variable to call its elements later and sum those values with the same type of line. I know that since its a file where lines are strings in order to operate with values they must be treated as ints so it should be something like int(y[1]), but I am not sure. Any suggestion whether I am on the right path?
Here is what I tried so far:

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        y = line.split(':')
        ...
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.
There are plenty of tutorials and Stack Overflow questions that show how to read and convert data such as this.  How are you stuck?  How are you not sure whether something works?  What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Sorry If I asked an off-topic question I just read the documentation and the how to ask rules.I will consider this next time. And I will try to look if the question was already answered. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic answer using the standard data types,  it isn't probably the most efficient way to do this, but it will help you learn the basics of python

A dict is a good choice for a intermediate data structure, 
as you can not have multiple keys of the same name.  We use this to sum your lines

```
    output = dict()  

    with open("file_name", "r") as file:
        for line in file.readlines(): 
            line_name, value = line.split(":")
            value.strip()  # Strip the new line character
            if line_name in output.keys():  # Test to see if we see this line before
                output[line_name] += int(value)  #  augmented addition operator
            else:
                output[line_name] = int(value) # line not found assign basic value

    for key, value in output.items():  # format the output in the way you wanted
        print("The sum of %s is %s" % (key, value))
```

Output:

```
The sum of Type of line 2 is 80
The sum of Type of line 1 is 30
The sum of Type of line 3 is 17
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to group the lines by line value, and then sum the trailing digits of each line:

```
import itertools
import re
file_data = [i.strip('\n') for i in open('filename.txt')]
new_data = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(file_data, key=lambda x:re.findall('(?<=line\s)\d+', x)), key=lambda x:re.findall('(?<=line\s)\d+', x))]
final_results = ['Type of line {}: {}'.format(a, sum(int(re.findall('\d+$', i)[0]) for i in b)) for [a], b in new_data]
```

Output:

```
['Type of line 1: 30', 'Type of line 2: 80', 'Type of line 3: 17']
```